# Tensorflow error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm not very experienced using Tensorflow, and I started using a Google Colab created by Max Woolf (https://minimaxir.com/2018/05/text-neural-networks/)

I've edited this post before as I had another simple error I corrected, but then now a bunch of new problems arose with that correction. I'm not experienced as I said, and there's a ton of errors I cannot understand.

I'm trying to train my machine to produce text from a training data file called "marselo", and I suddenly get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-207479944fff> in <module>()
----> 1 textgen = textgenrnn(name='marselo')
      2 
      3 train_function = textgen.train_from_file if train_cfg['line_delimited'] else textgen.train_from_largetext_file
      4 
      5 train_function(

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/textgenrnn/textgenrnn.py in __init__(self, weights_path, vocab_path, config_path, name)
     65         self.model = textgenrnn_model(self.num_classes,
     66                                       cfg=self.config,
---> 67                                       weights_path=weights_path)
     68         self.indices_char = dict((self.vocab[c], c) for c in self.vocab)
     69 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/textgenrnn/model.py in textgenrnn_model(num_classes, cfg, context_size, weights_path, dropout, optimizer)
     16     '''
     17 
---> 18     input = Input(shape=(cfg['max_length'],), name='input')
     19     embedded = Embedding(num_classes, cfg['dim_embeddings'],
     20                          input_length=cfg['max_length'],

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py in Input(shape, batch_shape, name, dtype, sparse, tensor)
    176                              name=name, dtype=dtype,
    177                              sparse=sparse,
--> 178                              input_tensor=tensor)
    179     # Return tensor including _keras_shape and _keras_history.
    180     # Note that in this case train_output and test_output are the same pointer.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, batch_input_shape, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name)
     85                                          dtype=dtype,
     86                                          sparse=self.sparse,
---> 87                                          name=self.name)
     88         else:
     89             self.is_placeholder = False

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in placeholder(shape, ndim, dtype, sparse, name)
    539         x = tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    540     else:
--> 541         x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
    542     x._keras_shape = shape
    543     x._uses_learning_phase = False

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

This is the code:

````
!pip install -q textgenrnn
from google.colab import files
from textgenrnn import textgenrnn
from datetime import datetime
import os


model_cfg = {
    'word_level': False,   # set to True if want to train a word-level model (requires more data and smaller max_length)
    'rnn_size': 128,   # number of LSTM cells of each layer (128/256 recommended)
    'rnn_layers': 3,   # number of LSTM layers (>=2 recommended)
    'rnn_bidirectional': False,   # consider text both forwards and backward, can give a training boost
    'max_length': 30,   # number of tokens to consider before predicting the next (20-40 for characters, 5-10 for words recommended)
    'max_words': 10000,   # maximum number of words to model; the rest will be ignored (word-level model only)
}

train_cfg = {
    'line_delimited': False,   # set to True if each text has its own line in the source file
    'num_epochs': 20,   # set higher to train the model for longer
    'gen_epochs': 5,   # generates sample text from model after given number of epochs
    'train_size': 0.8,   # proportion of input data to train on: setting < 1.0 limits model from learning perfectly
    'dropout': 0.0,   # ignore a random proportion of source tokens each epoch, allowing model to generalize better
    'validation': False,   # If train__size < 1.0, test on holdout dataset; will make overall training slower
    'is_csv': False   # set to True if file is a CSV exported from Excel/BigQuery/pandas
}

file_name = "marselo.txt"
model_name = 'marselo'   # change to set file name of resulting trained models/texts


textgen = textgenrnn(name=model_name)

train_function = textgen.train_from_file if train_cfg['line_delimited'] else textgen.train_from_largetext_file

train_function(
    file_path=file_name,
    new_model=True,
    num_epochs=train_cfg['num_epochs'],
    gen_epochs=train_cfg['gen_epochs'],
    batch_size=1024,
    train_size=train_cfg['train_size'],
    dropout=train_cfg['dropout'],
    validation=train_cfg['validation'],
    is_csv=train_cfg['is_csv'],
    rnn_layers=model_cfg['rnn_layers'],
    rnn_size=model_cfg['rnn_size'],
    rnn_bidirectional=model_cfg['rnn_bidirectional'],
    max_length=model_cfg['max_length'],
    dim_embeddings=100,
    word_level=model_cfg['word_level']) ```

What can I do to resolve this?
````

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textgen = textgenrnn(name=marselo)
```

This is trying to reference a variable called `marselo`, which doesn't exist.  You probably meant either

```
textgen = textgenrnn(name='marselo')
```

or

```
textgen = textgenrnn(name=model_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following code and my problem has resolved .

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the TensorFlow version installed ...Tensorflow latest version 
doesnt support placeholder attribute

https://botbark.com/2019/12/18/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-placeholder-tensorflow-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this:**

**For Google Colab:**

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

**For VSCode (Works well for Python 3.9.6 and TensorFlow 2.8.0):**

```
import tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```